# Parallel Trees On The Grass

Tags: mathematics, visual, rebus

[image]Let the picture speak for itself and try to find the correct height of the tree marked with "**?**".

Hint

> Side length 8

Hint2

> [image]

> The *bottom* distance..

Strong hint

> The figure inside the triangle describe whether or not it's the bottom/"root-to-root" distance/-s OR the top distance/-s

Comment: That picture does not speak for itself.

Comment: It does, but in a subtle way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

> The second image (together with the hints) suggest that the bottoms of the trees are set on the vertices of an equilateral triangle and the tops of the trees are the vertices of an isosceles triangle (with the top of the front tree further away).
>  Furthermore, the image and the hints seem to be suggesting that the long side of the isosceles triangle (representing the tops) is double the length of the side of the equilateral triangle (representing the bottoms).
>  Given that the distance between the bottoms is 8 (as given by the first hint), this indicates that the distance between the top of the front tree and either of the other trees is 16. The explanation for this would be that the front tree is taller.

Overall, we get the following image

> [image]
>  This represents the distances between the front (taller) tree and one of the rear trees.
>  Using Pythagoras' Theorem, we find that the difference in height between the trees is $$ \Delta h = \sqrt{16^2 - 8^2} = \sqrt{192} = 8\sqrt{3}$$

This would suggest that the unknown height is

> $10 + 8\sqrt{3}$

How do we work out the distance between the bottoms of the trees (thanks to OP for the explanation)

> In the second picture, there is a 16-gon just above the two triangles. This is to indicate that double the distance between the bottoms of the trees is 16, hence the distance between the bottoms is 8.

Comment: Forgot about this one. Good work! rot13(gur vagragvba jvgu gur 16-tba jnf gung vg ercerfragrq gur gbgny qvfgnapr bs *gjb* obggbzf (v.r 16, fb gur qvfgnapr bs bar = 8). Gevrq gb znqr vg uneqre gb haqrefgnaq gung gur obggbz qvfgnapr jnf 8)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Thank you, which is the 16-gon? Isn't that a shape with 16 sides?

Comment: Yes. Might have not been that clear and visible but if you zoom in on my original post, you'll see it exactly above the two triangles

Comment: @Prim3numbah Oh gosh, yes, sorry, I thought that was a dotted circle, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it does look like one. No prob :)